# How can I change the block size in mpeg-2 codec?

Tags: mpeg-2

The default size of a block in MPEG-2 encoder and decoder is 16*16. I am planning to write a motion estimation algorithm to see the effect of other block sizes on the output but I don't know how can I change the size of a block.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You have to do that in the motion estimation part of the encoder, no? Not a trivial task. Also you can do ME with blocks that are not 16*16 but you have to encode 16*16 to get standard mpeg2. Else you have to write your own decoder for decoding your streams. While you are at it, HEVC has introduced non 16*16 blocks if i remember right. So you may simply want to use their reference encoder and enable and disable 16*16 blocks and check the difference.